# error deploying static webpage build with nanoc on github with orphan git branch

Tags: git, github, nanoc

I followed [this tutorial on the nanoc webpage](https://nanoc.ws/doc/deploying/) to deploy my webpage on github.
I followed these instructions

```
% rm -rf output
% git clone . output
% cd output
output@master% git checkout --orphan gh-pages
output@gh-pages% git rm -rf 
output@gh-pages% git remote rm origin
output@gh-pages% git remote add origin repo-url
```

but when i want to run

```
nanoc 
nanoc deploy
```

i need to change in the base directory where the *nanoc.yaml* file is. But when switching i also change back(?) to the main branch from the gh-pages branch. I suppose that is because of the orphan nature of the branch, but this is just wildly guessing.

and nanoc terminates with this error message

```
Loading site… done                   
Deploying via Git to branch “gh_pages” on remote “origin”…                 
git@github.com:name/repo_name.git                              
error: pathspec 'gh_pages' did not match any file(s) known to git.         

Captain! We’ve been hit!             

Message:                             

Nanoc::Deploying::Deployers::Git::Errors::BranchDoesNotExist: The branch to deploy, gh_pages, does not exist.
```

This is the relevant part of the *nanoc.yaml* file. (the rest is the unchanged standard)

```
deploy:                          
  default:                       
    kind: git
    remote: git@github.com:name/repo_name.git
    branch: gh_pages
```

Hope someone can tell me where my ship has been hit and how i can avoid this ice rock ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the branch name in the Nanoc configuration. Change

```
branch: gh_pages
```

to

```
branch: gh-pages
```

(replace the underscore by a hypen) and the deploy should succeed.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but the typo was only here in sof ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error message was acutally quite clear:

```
The branch to deploy, gh_pages, does not exist.
```

On github i did not have the orphan branch. So after creating the branch in the output folder i pushed this branch i was able to use ´nanoc´ and ´nanoc deploy´
to automatically deploy the page.